# Symfony2 : Checking for old ROLE returns true

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using `FOSUserBundle` for my [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2) project. Upon registration, I check with the function below if the user has the default role `ROLE_USER` that FOSUB gives.

```
 /**
  * Returns true if user has ROLE_USER
  *
  * @return boolean 
  */
 public function hasDefaultRole() {
     return ($this->hasRole('ROLE_USER'));
 }
```

If this function returns true, I set up a new account registration form and on submit the roles are changed and `ROLE_USER` is removed.

**EDIT** :

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
...
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user->removeRole("ROLE_USER");
$user->setRoles(array("ROLE_TEACHER", "ROLE_TEACHER_BASIC"));
$user->setStatus(1);
$userManager->updateUser($user);
$this->resetToken($user);
```

restetToken does this  :

```
 $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
 $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

I have checked the database and there is no role user anymore. If I logout, and login back again, `$user->hasDefaultRole()` still returns true. What am I not seeing here? Or is this an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOSUserBundle always add the default role (`ROLE_USER`) to the list of roles to ensure that users always have at least on role, so no matter what you do you won't be able to remove it.

<kbd>FOSUserBundle\Model\User</kbd>

```
/**
 * Returns the user roles
 *
 * @return array The roles
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = $this->roles;

    foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
        $roles = array_merge($roles, $group->getRoles());
    }

    // we need to make sure to have at least one role
    $roles[] = static::ROLE_DEFAULT;

    return array_unique($roles);
}
```

<kbd>FOSUserBundle\Model\UserInterface</kbd>

```
const ROLE_DEFAULT = 'ROLE_USER';
```

Also you will never find the `ROLE_USER` in your database as it never actually adds it.

<kbd>FOSUserBundle\Model\User</kbd>

```
public function addRole($role)
{
    $role = strtoupper($role);
    if ($role === static::ROLE_DEFAULT) {
        return $this;
    }

    if (!in_array($role, $this->roles, true)) {
        $this->roles[] = $role;
    }

    return $this;
}
```